# Excel - How to convert US date string (dd-mmm-yyyy) to European date

Tags: excel, date, format

How can date in the US format dd-mmm-yyyy be converted to a date in European format.

When importing text based data with US Dates, some dates will import as a date, some import as a string.

A US date like 11-Jun-2021 is equal to NL format, so it will import as a date.
A US date like 11-Oct-2021 should be converted to 10-okt-2021, but it's imported as a string.

Is there a way to convert this string to a date format?

Comment: *"When importing text based data with US Dates, some dates will import as a date, some import as a string."* Are you really **IMPORTING**? If you are, there is an option to set the date format of the text file as `DMY` (legacy wizard) or `en-US` (Power Query).  If you are not actually doing an Import, but instead you are **OPENING** the file, change.  PQ would be the preferred method of import, since it should be able to also translate the month strings.

Comment: Also, what is the logic of converting `11-Oct-2021` to `10-okt-2021`? If that is not a typo, you will need to add some additional logic.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I think you mean 11-Oct-2021 to 10-Nov-2021

Comment: @taylor.2317 No, I don't think so. The OP wrote *"A US date like 11-Oct-2021 should be converted to 10-okt-2021"*.  I don't see where he mentioned *Nov* at all.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld apologies, didn't see that...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I mean is how to get from 28-Oct-2021 to 28-okt-2021 or 28-10-2021.

Comment: The dates come from an external program output in csv format. Dates are all outputted in the US-US format DD-MMM-YYYY. Our Excel locale is set at NL-NL and most dates are recognized as a date because most months have the same abbreviation in US and NL, except months like: Mar = Mrt, May = Mei, Oct = Okt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in Italian. A3 contains the original date (only 8 months need to be translated):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A3);A3;1*SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3;"Jan";"GEN");"May";"MAG");"Jun";"GIU");"Jul";"LUG");"Aug";"AGO");"Sep";"SET");"Oct";"OTT");"Dec";"DIC"))
```

Comment: Please properly format your answer

Answer (score 1):

Found something. It's kinda dirty, but it works:

```
=IF(C3=0;"";IF(IFERROR(FIND("Oct";C3;1);FALSE);REPLACE(C3;FIND("Oct";C3;1);3;"Okt");IF(IFERROR(FIND("May";C3;1);FALSE);REPLACE(C3;FIND("May";C3;1);3;"Mei");IF(IFERROR(FIND("Mar";C3;1);FALSE);REPLACE(C3;FIND("Mar";C3;1);3;"Mrt");C3))))
```